# Connecting to a mysql database from php, error but no error shown?

Tags: php, mysql, debian

so I'm making a super simple site just for practice where you type something in an then its displayed on the page, but it wont work and i think iv narrowed it down to the begining where it connects to the database just

```
$server    ="localhost";
$username  ="root";
$password  ="********";
$database  ="user_accounts"; 
$connect=mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password,$database);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
```

Im running my server using Apache/2.2.22 (Debian), PHP 5.4.4-14  and mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.31, for debian-linux-gnu (armv7l) using readline 6.2
and I've noticed that even when I type the password incorrectly it doesn't 'echo' the error line, so my question is do I connect to localhost like that or did i do something else wrong in there?

Comment: also i hate using the root login, if anyone could give me the sql code to make a read and write user only thatd help out a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Failed to connect: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you Try this

```
<?php
$mysqli = @new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '*******', 'user_accounts');

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    die('Connection Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Connect like below

```
<?php
$link = @mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '*******', 'user_accounts');

if (!$link) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_errno());
}
?>
```

Below is create user in mysql script on your request

User `newuser` to connect with no password (which is insecure), include no IDENTIFIED BY clause:

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost';
```

To assign a password to new created user `newuser`, use IDENTIFIED BY with the plaintext password value:

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

To avoid specifying the plaintext password if you know its hash value (the value that PASSWORD() would return for the password), specify the hash value preceded by the keyword PASSWORD:

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost'
IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*90E462C37378CED12064BB3388827D2BA3A9B689';
```

Then you can `GRANT` access of what ever you want to that `newuser`

`GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON user_accounts.* TO 'newuser'@'localhost';`

You can use this [link](http://danbarnett.net/scripts/hash.php) to generate the hash code.