# PHP connecting to database fails without error

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to connect to databse on my server by using this code:

```
<?php
 $username = "username";
 $servername = "localhost";
 $password = "password";
 echo "Before connection";

 // Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }
 echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

But code after `$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);` is not executing. When i try to echo anything after it I do not get output. Code before that line works as expected. I do not get any errors from php.

I am not sure what is problem. Could it be something server related? I did try to add:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

but it didn't help, no errors have been displayed.

I have been trying many things from stackoverflow (and other places) but they didnt help, some examples:

[Connecting to a mysql database from php, error but no error shown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683337/connecting-to-a-mysql-database-from-php-error-but-no-error-shown)

[Connection of MySQL with PHP not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41878840/connection-of-mysql-with-php-not-working)

Comment: Did you add those `ini_set` / `error_reporting` lines at the very beginning of your script? You should have log files stored by your webserver in any case.

Comment: @Jeto yes I did, and there are no errors in webservers log either...

Comment: I just use default server error handler. But this is school webserver so it might be lacking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to handle errors

Simplest of all, use try catch while connecting

```
<?php
 $username = "username";
 $servername = "localhost";
 $password = "password";
 echo "Before connection";

 // Create connection
 try {
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password); } catch(\Exception $e) { var_dump ('oopss... this is the error', $e)}
 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }
 echo "Connected
```

Comment: __Who__ told you that `new mysqli` __throws exception__?

Comment: Well it did help thank you I got error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in... 

So now is just to try to fix that :).

Comment: This was not necessarily to catch new mysqli errors but anything that could potentially go in between, and in OP's case that seemed more likely